# get Criteria.list by key

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have classes:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "oldusers")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
   ......
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userId", cascade =      CascadeType.ALL)
    List<User> usertList= new ArrayList<>(0);

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }
```

and

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class Usert implements Serializable {
    int userId;
    int position;
    String name;
    List<Exercise> list = new ArrayList<>(0);
    OldsUser userId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentid")
    public OldUser getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }
}
```

I need get all User by idOldUser.For that  I have written below code

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parentid", idOldUser));
```

But nothing get :(

Comment: error  org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: parentid of: ap.entity.User

Comment: You have two classes "User" and "Usert" and where is "OldsUser" or what is it exactly?

Comment: Two classes. Top is OlsUser, bottom is User

Comment: Try something like `criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId.xxx", idOldUser))` where `xxx` is the name of the field of the key in `OldUser` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit complicated but I think what you should need it changing criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId.id", idOldUser));
```

you parentId is actually oldUser. An you initialized your OldUser as userId in you Usert class (I belive Usert class shows the User class, and the class at the top shows the OldUser class depending on your comment)

Answer (score 0):

The Restriction.eq method needs to receive the mapped field name and not the column name, I can't quite understand the logic in your mappings, but here's an example of a criteria that should work:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usert.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", idOldUser));
```

If you want to query your `User` class, you'll need to map a field inside it, and use the restriction properly.

Comment: and if use generic instead User.claas:
Class<T> type;
............................
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type);
How can I use criteria?

Comment: and why when I geting OldUser from DB, I have OldUser.listUser = null? In DB in table ""user"  I see parentid = id OldUser.